# How two non related process know the same key to allocate same shared memory

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, ipc, shared-memory

I am learning shared memory IPC. I have some doubt.

Q1. Shared memory is used for related and non related process. And a process allocate a shared memory with `shemget` function. First parameter of this function is key. How two non related process know the same key to allocate same shared memory.

Q2. Whane we are using `shmget and shmat` function, new or existing(in using IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL) memory is created and mapped with process memory space. What are the section of process memory (like heap,bss) shared memory are mapped. And in shmat function if we pass shmaddr which is already in use then, how system will behave.

Q3.  What is the use case for giving fixed memory `addredd` in `shmat.`

Answer (score 2):

Refering 1:

> How two non related process know the same key to allocate same shared memory.

They either are told by a third entidy or they communicate it (to) each other.

---

Refering 2b:

> And in shmat function if we pass shmaddr which is already in use then, how system will behave.

`shmat()` will fail and return `(void*) -1`.

Comment: Like saving semid to a file. And both process can read that id.

Comment: Yes, but there are lots of possibilites to achieve the one or the other approach. @Abhiteshkhatri

Answer (score 1):

Re.2a. There are no sections in memory. Sections are in object files.

In more detail, organisation of the process address space in a typical Unix-like system does not necessarily correspond to that of an executable/object file. If you look at the output of `cat /proc/self/maps` on a Linux system, you will see a list of memory regions, some labeled with a name of a file in the last column, some unlabeled, and some labeled with strings like `[stack]`, `[heap]` and `[vdso]`. Regions labeled with names of executable/DSO files correspond to regions in these files, which may or may not be actual `text` or `bss` sections (there's no trace of the section name in the process memory space anyway). The special region names in brackets do not correspond to any file, they are just regions created for some particular purpose known to the loader. Unnamed regions are normally created by `mmap` but are not attached to any file. A shared memory region created by one of the `shm` functions is likely to be labeled with either `/dev/zero` or `SYSVnn` where `nn` is the key passed to `shmget()`.

Re. 3. One case that comes to mind is a shared data structure that contains internal pointers.

Comment: The claim about sections being in object files and not in memory is neither accurate nor clarifying.  What would be helpful would be to point out that there's typically a lot of other room in the process address space, and that the kernel can map pages into that in ways that don't necessarily correspond to compiler/linker/library concepts of memory organization.